# How to get to Ubuntu's home directory in Windows?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, home-folder

How can I get to Ubuntu's home directory in Windows?

Comment: This can not be answered without more information. Are the windows and the Ubuntu installation on the same computer? What filesystem did you use for the home partition on Ubuntu? If it is something common (e.g. ext2) then you can just add the driver for that to the windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

You need ext3 or ext4 partition in Ubuntu and some driver support for reading that type of partition from windows.

There are several applications for Windows that builtin support for ext3:

- [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs)
- [DiskInternals Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader)
- [Ext2 Installable
  File System](http://www.fs-driver.org/index.html)